# Why am i getting an error 404 when i run this code in laravel 9?

Tags: laravel, file-upload, routes, laravel-7, laravel-9

I was watching an old tutorial about **laravel 7** whiles using **laravel 9**, i tried to create a HTML form like this.

```
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                        <input type="file" name="image">
                        <input type="submit" value="upload">
                    </form>   
                  </div>
```

then in my route(web.php) i added a code like this

```
route::post('/upload', function(Request $request)
{$request->image->store('images', 'public');
return 'image uploaded succesfully';
```

but in my webiste it tells me page the url you requested is not found on the site serve

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Route` instead of `route` though?

Comment: @itachi Either will work.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined your route using `POST` meaning it will only respond to `POST` requests.

If you try to access `/upload` from a web browser, that uses a `GET` request which you've not defined a route for. So you want to define such a route:

```
Route::get('/upload', function () {
    return view('upload.blade.php');
});
```

You'll want to replace `upload.blade.php` with the name of your view that has your upload form in it.

Comment: the form has the method POST. So it will be a post request when submitted.

Comment: @itachi Indeed, but if the OP has not defined a `GET` route for viewing the form in the first instance...

Answer (score 0):

Name Your Route 1st , hit this command php artisan route:clear then try..

Change the form action action="{{ route('upload') }}"

```
 <div class="card-body">
                    <form action="{{ route('upload') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                        <input type="file" name="image">
                        <input type="submit" value="upload">
                    </form>   
                  </div>
```

Comment: Am sorry but it didn't work out. It still shows page not found

Comment: share both files code ,I think something else creating issue.